# Is there a way to default outofbound errors to 0?

Tags: java

For example if you have a string of size 5, and you do something like string.atChar(7), could you make that default to 0 instead of it returning as an error?

Comment: Make your own method? Or do a try catch on `charAt`?

Comment: filter the number you put in string.atChar(number) with a if
if(number > 5) number=0;

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Usually it's preferably to fail fast, instead of munging along and eventually producing wrong results much later. It would be a pain to debug such behavior.

Answer (score 1):

(I assume you mean charAt())

You can make your own charAt() method and put it inside a string utility class:

```
pulbic class MyStringUtility {
    public static char charAt(String string, int index) {
      if (index >= string.length) index = 0;

      return string.charAt(index);
    }
}
```

And then just call `MyStringUtility.charAt(string, 7)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean charAt(), put a `try catch` block around the `charAt(7)` code. In the catch block, return 0 for your method.

```
try {
  string.charAt(7);
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
  return 0;
}
```

That should work. :)